# Spring Boot OpenFeign: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-get, feign, openfeign

The examples below demonstrate the issues experienced when using OpenFeign. The problem becomes evident when your response object has too many fields, which throws an error: ***Method has too many parameters***. Example 1 works perfectly, but Example 2 fails.

Example 1 uses HTTP.POST with the same response object as used in Example 2, which uses HTTP.GET.

Why does OpenFeign limit the fields in an HTTP.GET method, and throw an exception? I can't use an HTTP.POST to get/fetch/read a resource. BAD REST API Design standards.

Using the same response object, for both HTTP.POST (which works), HTTP.GET fails

```
public interface ClientFeignV2 {

//Example 1 
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json") @RequestLine("POST api/v2/clients") ClientResponse findAllClientsByUid1(@RequestBody ClientRequest request);

//Example 2
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@RequestLine("GET api/v2/clients/{uid}")
ClientResponse findAllClientsByUid(@PathVariable(value = "uid") String uid,
                                         @RequestParam(value = "limit", required = false) Integer limit,
                                         @RequestParam(value = "offset", required = false) Integer offset);
}
```

StackTrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract com.services.requestresponse.ClientResponse com.microservice.gateway.feign.v2.ClientFeignV2.findAllClientsByUid(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer)
at feign.Util.checkState(Util.java:128) ~[feign-core-9.4.0.jar:na]
at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(Contract.java:114) ~[feign-core-9.4.0.jar:na]
at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidatateMetadata(Contract.java:64) ~[feign-core-9.4.0.jar:na]
at feign.ReflectiveFeign$ParseHandlersByName.apply(ReflectiveFeign.java:146) ~[feign-core-9.4.0.jar:na]
at feign.ReflectiveFeign.newInstance(ReflectiveFeign.java:53) ~[feign-core-9.4.0.jar:na]
at feign.Feign$Builder.target(Feign.java:209) ~[feign-core-9.4.0.jar:na]
at feign.Feign$Builder.target(Feign.java:205) ~[feign-core-9.4.0.jar:na]
at com.microservice.gateway.service.v2.impl.ClientServiceV2Impl.<init>(ClientServiceV2Impl.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:203) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
... 40 common frames omitted
```

I went through the OpenFeign documentation, and it supports the above implementation. If I can't find a solution to this issue, I would have to resort to a workaround and use `HTTP.POST` and `@RequestBody` which is not an ideal solution according to Rest-API design standards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the tags, you're using Spring Boot, obviously with Spring Cloud OpenFeign. And the thing is that you're mixing two different Feign contracts.

Annotations like `@RequestLine` and `@Headers` are from the [core feign library](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#interface-annotations). 
You can use it as a declarative HTTP client, and not only in Spring applications (it won't need to use Spring annotations in that case).

So, the correct "example 2" with plain Feign could be like:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@RequestLine("GET api/v2/clients/{uid}?limit={limit}&offset={offset}")
ClientResponse findAllClientsByUid(@Param("uid") String uid,
                                   @Param("limit") Integer limit,
                                   @Param("offset") Integer offset);
```

On the other hand, things like `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable` are from Spring Web.
They can be used if you have [Spring Cloud OpenFeign](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-openfeign) library (the core feign is one of its components btw).
This library brings support for [SpringMvcContract](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/master/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/support/SpringMvcContract.java), which, in its case, allows you to use usual Spring Web annotations for defining request mapping instead of Feign-specific ones.

In case of `SpringMvcContract`, "example 2" could be like:

```
@GetMapping(value = "api/v2/clients/{uid}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
ClientResponse findAllClientsByUid(@PathVariable(value = "uid") String uid,
                @RequestParam(value = "limit", required = false) Integer limit,
                @RequestParam(value = "offset", required = false) Integer offset);
```

It's worth to mention that in Spring Cloud OpenFeign [the second approach is used by default](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/master/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/FeignClientsConfiguration.java#L104). To change it back to plain Feign contract, define the custom `Contract` bean ([source](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults)):

```
@Bean
public Contract feignContract() {
    return new feign.Contract.Default();
}
```