# Feign error: Method has too many Body parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, feign

Soo, I am using the following api endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value="/api/data)
ResponseEntity<Data> getData(@AuthenticationPrincipal currentAuthenticatedUser, HttpServletRequest request);
```

This endpoint returns the following error when called through feign in a different microservice:

```
"Method has too many Body parameters".
```

Am I missing something? Because I don't use the `@RequestBody` and I don't use a body when calling my endpoint anyway. So why is this error being thrown?

Thank you in advance!

So what I did was that I upgraded the spring boot version to spring boot 3, and changed the package of HttpServletRequest from javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest to jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest. Before it worked marvelously, but just changing the package of one method property shouldn't change this thing drastically.

Comment: Not sure whether https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221388/spring-boot-openfeign-java-lang-illegalstateexception-method-has-too-many-body/60271238#60271238 has some helpfull hints